# Missing "Required" button in GIT pull request

Tags: github

I have setup `Branch protection` rule as shown below and created one PR and it was completed in Codefresh CI pipeline. However I still can't see the `Required` button in the PR.
I suspect becuse of missing status check as shown below.
However I assume after at least one CI build run this would show?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't look like a `git` question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Troubleshooting required status checks](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/collaborating-on-repositories-with-code-quality-features/troubleshooting-required-status-checks)

Comment: @Justinas I also currently have this problem with GitHub but the troubleshooting guide hasn't helped. I'm using Xcode Cloud and it doesn't appear in the status checks.